# Invalid test command

Tags: ember-cli

I'm curious how we can autotest and manually test our applications with ember-cli? I've tried the following below, but I'm getting `test is invalid`

Not sure if anyone else is having this issue?

```
➜  sample-project git:(master) ✗ npm test

> sample-project@0.0.0 test /Users/alvincrespo/workspace/sample-project
> ember test

The specified command test is invalid, for available options see `ember help`

➜  sample-project git:(master) ✗ ember test
The specified command test is invalid, for available options see `ember help`

➜  sample-project git:(master) ✗ ember --version
ember-cli 0.0.20
➜  sample-project git:(master) ✗ npm --version
1.4.3
➜  sample-project git:(master) ✗ node --version
v0.10.26
```

Answer (score 1):

After running `ember server`, go in your browser to `http://localhost:4200/tests`. You'll see "EmberCli Tests".